# jpages plugin apply after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

I am currently working on this project.
This is the link to see results.

[tigermom2/school-search/](http://dev.jumpcatch.com/tigermom2/school-search/)

I have applied pagination with [jPages](http://luis-almeida.github.com/jPages/) plugin.
Pagination works fine for the first time along with sorting.
But when you change the filters on the left side, pagination works but sorting gives fluctuation.

jPages plugin is activated before AJAX load. We need to deactivate plugin and reactivate it after AJAX page content is loaded.
How to deactivate and reactivate jPages plugin?

How to initiate plugin after page AJAX content loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-initiate jPages plugin after ajax call either on success or done.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'your ajax page url',
      type: 'Either POST or GET',
      data: 'Data to be sent to ajax page',
      success: function(){
               $("div.holder").jPages({
                  containerID: "pageContainer",
                  perPage : 5
               });
             }
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'your ajax page url',
      type: 'Either POST or GET',
      data: 'Data to be sent to ajax page',

}).done(function(){
   $("div.holder").jPages({
                  containerID: "pageContainer",
                  perPage : 5
               });
});
```

Comment: it works with ajax. It is imperative that ItemContainer does not have attribute 'display: none' what can happen before displaying a page